# How frequently should I expect Google AdsBot to visit my site?

Tags: web-crawlers, googlebot, advertising, cpc-ads

I bought paid advertising for my website through an internet advertising company. I noticed that, among all the visits coming from that source, a large amount of them have `AdsBot-Google (+http://www.google.com/adsbot.html)` as their User Agent. This is close to 150 clicks per hour, which means around 50% of all incoming requests that have this particular advertiser as their utm_source.

Is this the bot's regular behaviour? I know that having this bot visiting my landing pages is to be expected, but I'm not sure whether so many visits is the norm, or there is something fishy with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well don't worry about it. Its great that google bots are crawling your websites as it may increase your websites google index.

I think googlecrawlers crawls your website everyday and the frequency depends on the many factors like inbound links, frequent site changes, server connectivity.